# Windows server 2012 R2: iis not available after hyperv install

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2

**Following setup**:

Physical Win2012 R2 Server "HOST1" running:

- Single networking card "NIC1"
- IIS
- Some Webservices
- HyperV

Virtual Win2008 Server "HOST2" running on HOST1 in HyperV:

- IIS
- Some Webservices

**Problem description:**

HOST2 was previously a physical server, which crashed and so i converted it to a virtual server. I now run it as HyperV guest on HOST1. From internal LAN, everything works just as it did before. The only problem is, that now neither HOST1 nor HOST2 are accessible from public internet (which worked before).

I configured HOST1 to be an HyperV host and added one virtual (external) switch "SWITCH1". HOST2 uses SWITCH1 as ethernet adapter.

Since this action, neither HOST2 nor HOST1 are accessible from public internet, but are accessible from internal lan.

I looked at the properties of NIC1 on HOST1, and it showed that none of the (previously) checked elements (IP4, IP6, Client for Microsoft Networks, etc) are checked, but on SWITCH1 they are. Only checked option in NIC1 is "HyperV - extendable virtual switch" (please excuse the translations of the elements - I use german windows and translated them).

If I try to enable these properties on NIC1, neither HOST1 nor HOST2 are accessible, even in private lan.

Any Ideas how to fix this? Or any ideas what can be the problem?

Regards, Christian.

Comment: Good old typo in network configuration...

Comment: Standardgateway was wrong

Comment: Closing because it's a typo and nothing else

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in network configuration, standard gateway was wrong...